# TypeError: Cannot read property 'color' of undefined

Tags: reactjs

I am getting a Type Error  that says Cannot read property 'color' of undefined

```
 renderMessage(message) {
 const {member, text} = message;
 const {currentMember} = this.props;
 const messageFromMe = member.id === currentMember.id;
 const className = messageFromMe ?
      "Messages-message currentMember" : "Messages-message";
    return (
      <li className={className}>
      <span
        className="avatar"
        style={{backgroundColor: member.clientData.color}}
      />
        <div className="Message-content">
          <div className="username">
            {member.clientData.username}
          </div>
          <div className="text">{text}</div>
        </div>
     </li>
    );
  }
}
```

The code is compiling in node js but it outputs a error message in the browser

Comment: Have you done any debugging to see why `clientData` is undefined?

Comment: i have done a bit i am allot sure that it is a syntax problem but i cant seem to see the member of client data

Comment: Follow the logs. If `clientData` is undefined, that means something is wrong with the `member` property, which means the `message` param passed in is not what you expect